# Sprite Kit never detect my collision

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

When player body meet a monster body the function `func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)` is never called.

My class implement `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

the property `collisionBitMask` i commented it because i read that if we don't put it, node can collise with all node

I add my player like this :

```
bear.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.width/20, y:self.frame.height/5)
bear.size = CGSize(width:  self.frame.width/7, height:  self.frame.height/5)
bear.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bear.frame.size)
bear.physicsBody?.dynamic = false;
bear.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
bear.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
//bear.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
```

I add monster like this:

```
           let thePosition = CGPoint(x: positionX, y: (self.frame.height/7.4)*positionY)

        let monster =  SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: pattern as String)
        monster.size = CGSize(width:  self.frame.width/16, height:  self.frame.height/11)
        monster.name = name
        monster.position = thePosition


         monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: monster.frame.size)



        monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster // 3
        monster.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player // 4
        //platformNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player // 5


        addChild(monster)
```

**my PhysicalCategory**

```
struct PhysicsCategory {
  static let None      : UInt32 = 0
  static let All       : UInt32 = UInt32.max
  static let Player: UInt32 = 0b1      // 1
  static let Monster   : UInt32 = 0b10       // 2
  static let Projectile: UInt32 = 0b100      // 3
  static let Plateforme: UInt32 = 0b1000      // 4
}
```

I have multiple Textures, for example when player walk i call this :

```
    func walkingBear() {
    bear.runAction(    SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(bearCoursFrames, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true)), withKey:"cours")
  }
```

I initlaise bearCoursFrames like this

```
  var walkFrames = [SKTexture]()
    var numImages : Int = bearAnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count
    for var i=1; i<=numImages/2; i++ {
        let bearTextureName = "cours\(i)"
        walkFrames.append(bearAnimatedAtlas.textureNamed(bearTextureName))
    }

    bearCoursFrames = walkFrames
```

Where is my error please, i can't find a solution in other post 
any help would be appreciated

---------------------------------EDIT------------------------------
Solution: I just add self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add

```
       self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

and it works now.

Comment: Lol yeah, I assumed you did that already... It is not enough just to make SKScene to conforms to SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol...

Comment: I completely forget and i lost several hours searching solution lol, but your response helped me because i didn't know for dynamic that i have to enable at least one, and showing phisical body also :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. There is a rule which says that at least one body has to be defined as dynamic in order to register the contact.

Change either player or other body to be dynamic and contact will be detected.

As an addition, if you already haven't, enable physics visual representation ... It can be helpful because sometimes contact is not detected because the actual bodies are not intersecting each other eg. when node's anchor point is changed, so the texture and a body are misplaced (which is fixable, using appropriate initializers of SKPhysicsBody class, but this is a very common error).

Comment: I Just try it, dynamic = true, but i have the same problem, when i put this bear.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask when player meet monster body he change direction, and never meet him, in the two cases didBeginContact never called :(

Comment: i enabled enable physics visual representation i can see the two body met

Comment: Okay, will look at your example closely when I get in front of computer.

Comment: when i use dynamic = true in the two object  without collisionBitMask the two body change direction when they met 

when i use dynamic = true  in the two objects and collisionBitMask in the two objects, player when get closer of monster he push him, and never met him, it's strange !!!

Comment: Error was that i forget self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self, thanks for tour helps